# Internet Explorer 9+ has problems resizing a flash object in a table

Tags: html, flash, internet-explorer

I have a flash-based video player that is embedded in a html-table based layout. The expected behaviour is that the video player resizes automatically, depending on the size of the browser window. This works well in many tested browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Internet Explorer up to 8).

In IE 9 and 10, tested on Windows 7 and 8.1, resizing works well in the x-axis, and enlarging works well in the y-axis. However, when the user shrinks the window size vertically, the flash player size stays the same and IE "helpfully" adds a vertical scrollbar to the window, instead of adapting the size to fill the smaller space.

The smallest possible HTML code that I came up with to demonstrate this behaviour is:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>simplest testcase</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"><tr><td>
     <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
      style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" data="jwplayer.flash.swf"></object>
   </td></tr></table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that it does not depend on jwplayer, I was able to reproduce the problem with any .swf I tried. Also note that jwplayer rightfully displays an error message for missing configuration - this is not the problem, it's just about the resizing of the flash object in the HTML page. Also note that IE 8 and below do not understand the <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash"> method of embedding - again, this is not the problem here; a more complex page that uses the appropriate embedding method displays the same problem.

This example html page can be accessed at http://guardian.werft22.net/public/test-ie.html

When I replace the <object> with an <img> resizing works as expected, suggesting the problem is not entirely within IE's size-determining-engine.

Removing the table around the Flash object makes it work correctly as well. However, the original embedded video player is a quite complex table-based layout beast, and I'd like to avoid having to re-engineer it.

When I add

```
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
```

into the HTML header to force IE to downgrade to a different rendering method, it works correctly.

So, now my questions: Has anybody ever experienced something like this? If so, is there a more elegant workaround?

Does anybody has any ideas on whom (and how) to report this bug to? Microsoft or Adobe?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution for this?

Comment: No, I am not aware of any solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem embedding a Silverlight component in an object tag.
The solution was to add style="position: absolute;" on the object tag and style="position: relative" on the td tag. The last (relative) tag is important if you have elements that are supposed to be placed above the embedded element, or else you may see that the elements are placed on top of each other.
Seems to be a bug? when using default positioning.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>simplest testcase</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position:relative"><tr><td>
     <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
      style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position=absolute;" data="jwplayer.flash.swf"></object>
   </td></tr></table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this information! Unfortunately, when I load the modified testcase in IE 11 (latest one on Windows 7, 11.0.9600.17501 update version 11.0.15 (KB3008923)) it still acts the same :(